# Auto-refresh a side-bar through a BrowserHelperObject when i get focus on a tab page

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, refresh, bho, sidebar

I have a sidebar(iframe) that has its own instance on each tab you open. The thing is, the sidebar could be refreshed on tab 1 and not on tab 2. So i want to refresh the sidebar automatically when the user switch to another tab. Ex: user click on tab 2 and the BHO(BrowserHelperObject) refresh the sidebar right away. *If anyone need precisions, please ask. I'll be checking for responses every single days.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sink [DWebBrowserEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283(VS.85).aspx) and respond to the [WindowStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768307(v=VS.85).aspx) event.